# How to handle limitation of Dynamodb BatchWriteItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Just wondering whats the best way to handle the fact that dynamodb can only write batch sizes of max 25.

I have 3 Lambdas (there are more but I am simplifying down so we don't get side tracked)

1. GetNItemsFromExternalSourceLambda
2. SaveAllToDynamoDBLambda
3. AnalyzeDynamoDBLambda

Here is what happens:

- GetNItemsFromExternalSourceLambda can potentially fetch **250** items in 1 rest call it makes to an external api.
- It then invokes SaveAllToDynamoDBLambda and passes a) all these items and b)  paging info e.g. {pageNum:1, pageSize : 250, numPages:5  }   in the payload
- SaveAllToDynamoDBLambda needs to save all items to a dynamodb table and then , based on the paging info will either a) re-invoke GetNItemsFromExternalSourceLambda (to fetch next page of data) or b) invoke AnalyzeDynamoDBLambda
- these steps can loop many times obviously until we have got all the data from the external source before finally proceeding to last step
- the final AnalyzeDynamoDBLambda then is some lambda that processes all the data that was fetched and saved to the db

So my problems lies in fact that SaveAllToDynamoDBLambda can only write 25 items in a batch, which means I would have to tell my GetNItemsFromExternalSourceLambda to only fetch 25 items at a time from the external source which is not ideal. (being able to fetch 250 at a time would be a lot better)

One could extend the timeout period of the SaveAllToDynamoDBLambda so that it could do multiple batch writes inside one invocation but i dont like that approach.

I could also zip up the 250 items and save to s3 in one upload which could trigger a stream event but I would have same issue on the other side of that solution.

just wondering whats a better approach while still being able to invoke AnalyzeDynamoDBLambda only after all info from all rest calls has been saved to dynamodb.

Comment: I'd do it using recursive batch write calls with 25 items in each call provided that the maximum timeout allows putting all items in all pages into DynamoDB in a single lambda invocation.

Comment: A solution like this is very susceptible to data loss. You need to make sure that your data is durably stored at every step

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is you need a way of subdividing the large batch (250 items in this case) down to batches of 25 of less.

A very simple solution would be to use a Kinesis stream in the middle. Kinesis can take up to 500 records per [PutRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) call. You can then use [GetRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html) with a `Limit` of 25 and put the records into Dynamo with a single [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) call.

Make sure you look at the size limits as well before deciding if this solution will work for you.

Comment: yeah I also was thinking of kinesis, but its a managed service that is charged by the hour and it seems like overkill for this use case. One question @tom - with kinesis is it possibel to detect when the data has finished . I know eventually one can receive an empty [] result but that may just mean that data has not fully arrived yet. One could add a special 'end message' marker but i think order is not always preserved either.

Comment: I think I am going to go with a solution like this: 1. GetTotalCountItems ans store somewhere as a marker 2.GetNItemsFromExternalSourceLambda 2. call a ListIteratorLambda to iterate over the 250 one by one 3. call a PutOnSNSLambda which will put each one individually on a sns message (and iterate and page more if needed) 4. Consume message with an idempotent consumer lambda where i save each individually to dynamodb, 5. Use dynamodb steaming to increment a counter somewhere which can be compared to original stored count - when they are same then I can invoke Analyze lambda

Comment: @1977 There isn't a good way to see when a worker is done.  You could do the end marker if it's really important to know when it's finished, order is preserved.

Comment: @1977 with your proposed solution, I would be concerned about data loss. What happens is ListIteratorLambda fails in the middle? I would also be concerned about the concurrency of your lambda functions since sns will call the subscribed function concurrently. Lastly, I would be concerned about what happens when Dynamo's write throughput is reached and throttles your requests.

Comment: @1977 I would also double check, will you actually be saving any money given all of the extra invocations and the higher write through that will likely be required by Dynamo. Even, if you do save a little, simple designs tend to be better. Fewer thing to break and fewer things to debug when they do. I would ask yourself what your time is worth.

Comment: I can work out when a job is done by using dynamo streaming to atomically updating a counter in a control table. When counter == 'expectedCount' column there then that is my trigger @tom

Comment: each lambda is invoking next lambda with 'event' invocationtype, so I can add a retry policy there with a DLQ @tom

Comment: before my job I can also increase the dynamodb provision capacity.

Comment: kinesis would be nice to use though @tom